# Multi-Core OpenCL

Tags: c++, multithreading, gpu, opencl

I would like to execute some code on different cores of my GPU (Apple MacBook) in cpp / OpenCL, and found the code below that can execute code on what seems a single core. How to adapt it to send the code to multiple cores ?

```
int gpu = 1;
clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, gpu ? CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);
  
// Create a compute context 
//
context = clCreateContext(0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
 
// Create a command commands
//
commands = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &err);

// Create the compute program from the source buffer
//
program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) & KernelSource, NULL, &err);

// Build the program executable
//
err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// Create the compute kernel in the program we wish to run
//
kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "square", &err);

// Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
//
input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);
output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(float) * count, NULL, NULL);

// Write our data set into the input array in device memory 
//
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, data, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Set the arguments to our compute kernel
//
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(unsigned int), &count);

// Get the maximum work group size for executing the kernel on the device
//
clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel, device_id, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(local), &local, NULL);

// Execute the kernel over the entire range of our 1d input data set
// using the maximum number of work group items for this device
//
global = count;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel, 1, NULL, &global, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Wait for the command commands to get serviced before reading back results
//
clFinish(commands);
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ control structure code that launches OpenCL kernels almost always is single-threaded. A single core is more than enough to feed the GPU with kernels and keep the queue full at any time. Using several threads to enqueue kernels faster makes little sense.

If you want to run OpenCL kernels on a multi-core CPU instead of a GPU, just select the CPU as OpenCL device. OpenCL code on CPU always runs on all cores. While the CPU likely has more memory available, expect it to be much slower than even the integrated GPU.

---

For a simple start with OpenCL and C++, have a look at this open source [OpenCL-Wrapper](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm indeed able to send multiple calculations to each of my CPU threads, but unsure how to do with GPU. Having multiple GPU cores should help me to accelerate even more my calculation. Now what's the difference between Cores, Kernels and Threads ?

Comment: Make yourself clear that CPU parallelization in C++ (domain-decomposition) is fundamentally different from GPU parallelization (vectorization/SIMD); Google these terms. For GPU, you only need 1 CPU thread that tells the GPU which kernels to run. A kernel is something like the inside of a for-loop, but all iterations (can be millions, each with its own index) run in parallel. One single of these iterations is called a GPU thread (also called work item). A core is a physical arithmetic logical unit on the silicon. A CPU has ~2-16 cores, a GPU has ~500-15000 cores. Cores execute threads.

Comment: Clear, thanks a lot for your explanation to a newbie !